# Disable and record windows shortcuts

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am trying to record key combinations from the user.

Bellow the code work fine for stuff like `ctr+A` and it even record `win-key`, even though it does not stop it's effects.

But if I want to record stuff like `ctr+alt+del`, `alt+tab` or `alt+F4` it doesn't record at all!

```
CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += handleKey;

private void handleKey(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
        {
            bool isKeyDown = args.EventType.HasFlag(CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.KeyDown);
            bool isKeyUp   = args.EventType.HasFlag(CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.KeyUp);
            var isKeyReleaseOrWasNotDownAlready = args.KeyStatus.IsKeyReleased || !args.KeyStatus.WasKeyDown;

            if ((isKeyDown || isKeyUp) && isKeyReleaseOrWasNotDownAlready)
            {
                args.Handled = true;
                triggerKeyEvent(args);//sends event to a recorder
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to stop hotkey propagation and record it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that using `KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor` works for everything except `ctr+alt+del` or `win+L` but those combinations cannot ever be blocked anyway.

Remember to add `<rescap:Capability Name="inputForegroundObservation"/>` restricted capability.